# woocommerce WP страница Shop и категории

Tags: wordpress

Как перенести текст странице Shop и категориях в под товары woocommerce WP?
Я перетянул себе папку woocommerce в тему, правлю в файлах, но ничего не происходит. Правил **archive-product.php**, даже удалял, все без изменений.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Какую-такую "папку woocommerce "? Нужно копировать только шаблоны из каталога `templates` См https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: И не всю папку templates надо тянуть, а только нужный шаблон из нее, в аналогичный путь под темой. А то достался один сайт, где разраб вытянул всю папку templates, я потом запарился разбираться, что используется, а что нет. А разбираться пришлось, WC обновился много раз, ругается на старые шаблоны.

Comment: Более того, в одной из последних версий (кажется, начиная с 3.3), WC перестал загружать шаблоны из темы, если версия шаблона не соответствует версии того же шаблона в WooCommerce.

Comment: исправляюсь - вытянул шаблоны с `templates`

Comment: касательно обновлений посмотрю, спасибо за рекомендацию.

Comment: Обновил, не помогает. Но заметил одну вещь, когда комментирую в самом плагине папку `templates` то текст все равно вверху остается, а товары пропадают.

Comment: Для вывода `woocommerce` страниц, я использовал `woocommerce.php`, то есть создал его. Внутри вставил функцию `<?php woocommerce_content(); ?>` возможно что то не правильно или недостаточно этого кода?